# what's wrong in my Bmi Calculater App - kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner

- Hey all I am new in android, and I have made a simple BMi calculator in
  this I have a `spinner` to select a value, and I have to make a calculator
  which can change the value after making a `spinner` selection, I am not getting any error but I am note able to see an answer.

Please check what I have done wrong in this

```
   ' class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var valueofHeightInCm: Double = 0.0
    var valueofHeighInInch: Double = 0.0
    var valueofHeightInMeter: Double = 0.0
    var showResult: Double = 0.0
    var enterWeight: Double = 0.0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        try {
            valueofHeightInCm = et_enterheight.text.toString().toDouble() / 100
            valueofHeighInInch = et_enterheight.text.toString().toDouble() * 2.54
            valueofHeightInMeter = et_enterheight.text.toString().toDouble() * 0.01
            enterWeight = et_enterweight.text.toString().toDouble()
        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
          Toast.makeText(this,"please Entter input",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        val heightMeasure = resources.getStringArray(R.array.height)
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, heightMeasure)
        spinner1.adapter = adapter

        spinner1.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {

                when (position) {
                 0-> {
                        et_enterheight.setHint("Enter Height in Cm")
                        showw_result.setOnClickListener {
                            showResult = (enterWeight / (valueofHeightInCm * valueofHeightInCm))
                            tv_showResult.text = "%.2f".format(showResult)

                        }
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        et_enterheight.setHint("Enter Height in Inch")
                        showw_result.setOnClickListener {
                            showResult =
                                (enterWeight / (valueofHeighInInch * valueofHeighInInch)).toDouble()
                            tv_showResult.text = "%.2f".format(showResult)

                        }
                    }
                    2 -> {
                        et_enterheight.setHint("Enter Height in Meter")
                        showw_result.setOnClickListener {
                            showResult =
                                (enterWeight / (valueofHeightInMeter * valueofHeightInMeter))
                            tv_showResult.text = "%.2f".format(showResult)

                        }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }
```